# How to decode stellar XDR

Tags: stellar-sdk, xdr, go-sdk

I am working on stellar blockchain and need to decode stellar XDR which is in GO language. I know how to decode using JavaScript but couldn't find a way to do it in GO.

```
//JS code

const {Transaction} = require('stellar-base')

const parsedTx = new Transaction('tx_envelope_encoded_as_XDR')
console.log(parsedTx)
```

This works fine. what i have tried and not working...

```
//GO code

import (

  "bytes"
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "github.com/stellar/go/xdr"
  "github.com/gorilla/mux"

)

func DecodeXDR(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

var OBJ model.TransactionCollectionBody
err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&OBJ)
if err != nil {
  w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("Error while Decoding the body")
  fmt.Println(err)

  return
}

// fmt.Println(OBJ)

// lol:=xdr.Value(OBJ.XDR)

var txe xdr.Transaction
err = xdr.SafeUnmarshalBase64(XDRB64, &txe)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}

fmt.Println(txe)
```

}

```
//Output
{{PublicKeyTypePublicKeyTypeEd25519 0xc042055d20} 200 2800572080062465 <nil> {MemoTypeMemoNone <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil>} [{<nil> {OperationTypeManageData <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> 0xc042174040 <nil>}} {<nil> {OperationTypeManageData <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> 0xc042174080 <nil>}}] {0}}

//Expected Output

{ type: 'payment', destination: 'GCKUXI3JRJANYOF3AM35Z22FGUGYYUIEBPE5TTZ7P3G6XAEFGYZC2POM', asset: Asset { code: 'Blog', issuer: 'GDOPTRADBVWJR6BMB6H5ACQTAVUS6XMT53CDNAJZLOSTIUICIW57ISMF' }, amount: '10' }

{ type: 'payment', destination: 'GCKUXI3JRJANYOF3AM35Z22FGUGYYUIEBPE5TTZ7P3G6XAEFGYZC2POM', asset: Asset { code: 'Blog', issuer: 'GDOPTRADBVWJR6BMB6H5ACQTAVUS6XMT53CDNAJZLOSTIUICIW57ISMF' }, amount: '10' }

{ type: 'payment', destination: 'GCKUXI3JRJANYOF3AM35Z22FGUGYYUIEBPE5TTZ7P3G6XAEFGYZC2POM', asset: Asset { code: 'Blog', issuer: 'GDOPTRADBVWJR6BMB6H5ACQTAVUS6XMT53CDNAJZLOSTIUICIW57ISMF' }, amount: '10' }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Its good that you mentioned how it will work in JS. That will help some other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var txe xdr.Transaction
err = xdr.SafeUnmarshalBase64(TDP.XDR, &txe)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

You can use above code to Unmarshal Base64 XDR. And using &txe you can retrieve what ever value you need.